# Add every 10th element to a new <ul>

Tags: jquery, json

I have some input from a json call which gives me a very large list of 30 brands. 
I want to divide the list in three seperate ul. So every ul has 10 brands in it.

What I have is this:

HTML:

```
              <ul class="column_1">

              </ul>
              <ul class="column_2">

              </ul>
              <ul class="column_3">

              </ul>
```

Jquery:

```
          <script type="text/javascript">                           
            $.getJSON('http://link.to.brands/?format=json', function(data){
              var count = 1;
              $.each(data.brands, function(index, brand){
              $('<li><a href="'+brand.url+'" title="'+brand.title+'">'+brand.title+'</a></li>').appendTo('.block.third .column_'+count);
              count++
              });

            });
          </script>
```

Now the first three brands are placed in the ul's instead of blocks of 10. So I think my approach is wrong. 
How do I do this. Some explaination is more then welcome!

Comment: You're basically there. Just replace `count++` with `count = (count % 3) + 1`, so that after the third column it wraps back to `column_1` again, instead of trying `column_4` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.getJSON('http://link.to.brands/?format=json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.brands, function (index, brand) {
        $('<li><a href="' + brand.url + '" title="' + brand.title + '">' + brand.title + '</a></li>').appendTo('.block.third .column_' + (Math.floor(index / 10) + 1));
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you mean modulo (`%`) 10 at the end there

Comment: @Deryck no modulo is wrong because `5%10` will give 5 not 1 but `5/10 + 1)` will give 1

Comment: @Deryck that also will not work as `10 % 15` will give 15 we need 2 as the answer `Math.floor(15/10) + 1` will give 2

Comment: @Deryck thanks anyway as your comments lead me to another bug related to flooring of the division

Comment: Or `Math.ceil(index/10)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko what will happen to `Math.ceil(0/10)` we need 1

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to append to columns: `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...`

If you want:

```
B1  | B2  | B3
B4  | B5  | B6
B7  | B8  | B9
B10 | B11 | B12
B13 | B14 | B15
B16 | B17 | B18
B19 | B20 | B21
B22 | B23 | B24
B25 | B26 | B27
B28 | B29 | B30
```

then you're basically there: just replace

```
count++
```

with

```
count = (count % 3) + 1
```

### If you want the first 10 brands into column_1, next 10 into column_2, ...

Alternatively, if you want:

```
B1  | B11 | B21
B2  | B12 | B22
B3  | B13 | B23
B4  | B14 | B24
B5  | B15 | B25
B6  | B16 | B26
B7  | B17 | B27
B8  | B18 | B28
B9  | B19 | B29
B10 | B20 | B30
```

then change your `.appendTo` to:

```
.appendTo('.block.third .column_' + (Math.floor(index / 10) + 1))
```

and you can get rid of your `count` variable altogether.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for (the second one). Nevertheless your code doesn't work. Do you have an other solution?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVd5X/3/ ...Please post your HTML (I wonder if you meant `.block.third.column_` instead of `.block.third .column_` or something?

Comment: Well the code is working but the outcome of (Math.floor(index / 10) + 1) is nothing or wrong. The li items aren't appended to a column because everyting is appended to column_ instead of column_1 or 2 or 3 etc. But just curious... is index/10 + 1 not just 4??

Comment: `index` counts up from `0` to `29` automatically as your `$.each(data.brands, function(index, brand){` loop iterates. So no, it will never get to 4 (until there was a 31st brand). Double check that you do in fact call the first parameter `index` on that line. It will be `1` for the first 10 brands, then `2`, for the next 10, then `3` for the final 10. Is the example at http://jsfiddle.net/ZVd5X/3/ working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var _licount = 30;
        var _liperul = _licount / 3;

        $('ul').each(function () {

            var str = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < _liperul; i++) {

                str += '<li>Hello</li>';
            }
            $(this).append(str);

        });


    });

</script>
```